# Excel VBA: Search Folder and Sub-Folders for Part Numbers Listed in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Beginner in VBA so sorry if the code is bad.

What I wanted to achieve was to search a folder and its sub folders for the .dxf file of a part number listed in Column B, and return either a "Yes" or "No" depending on whether that .dxf file exist in that folder or its sub folders.

What I expected was that the code would begin with the first part number listed in B2, search the folder and sub folders for the .dxf file related, return a value, then move on to the next one, B3 then B4 and so on until the part numbers stop.

What it does is search a folder for all listed part numbers in Column B, returns all values, then searches a subfolder, returns all values (overriding the previous results) and so on until there are no more subfolders to search.

I feel like I'm close to getting the result I want but not sure where I've gone wrong.
Code is below:

```
Option Explicit
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String

Sub FindFile()
HostFolder = "C:\Users\Anyone\DXF\"

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

End Sub
Sub DoFolder(Folder)

Dim SubFolder
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Extension As String
Dim Continue As Boolean

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    DoFolder SubFolder
Next
Dim File
For Each File In Folder.Files

Continue = True
Extension = ".DXF"
Row = 2

While Continue
    If Len(Range("B" & CStr(Row)).Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If Len(Dir(Folder.Path & "\" & Range("B" & CStr(Row)).Value & "*" & Extension)) = 0 Then
            Range("F" & CStr(Row)).Value = "No"
        Else
            Range("F" & CStr(Row)).Value = "Yes"
    End If

    Row = Row + 1

Wend
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I would change the flow of this top down. Have your main macro loop through the rows in Column B. Inside that loop, call a function that returns TRUE/FALSE for a folder being present. That function would loop through each folder and EXIT as TRUE when a target value is found.

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink the approach here. Maybe try a macro to manage the row loop and a function to manage the file lookup

1. First macro to loop through all file names in `Column B` and outputs if a file is found in `Column C`
2. Second macro to search a folder/subfolder path. If the file is found, the loop ends and returns `TRUE`. If a file is not found, the macro runs it's course and exists with `FALSE`

Note the function is just demonstrating the logic. You just need to take the logic you have to manage the folder loop and implement in this function

---

```
Sub File_Range()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long, i As Long

lr = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lr
    If Not IsEmpty(ws.Range("B" & i)) Then
        ws.Range("C" & i) = File_Exists(Range("B" & i))
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function File_Exists(Target As Range) As Boolean

'False until file is found
File_Exists = False

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    If Len(Dir(Folder.Path & "\" & Target.Value & "*" & Extension)) Then
        File_Exists = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next SubFolder


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

### Check Files for Existence

**The Basics**

- Basically (inaccurately), the following writes all file paths of the required (`DXF`) files found in the supplied folder path to an array, replaces them with file names without file extension and checks the values (file names) in the source column against the array and finally writes the required results (`Yes`/`No`) to the destination column.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- Only run `checkFiles`, the rest is being called by it.

**Additional Functionality**

- To better understand the flow, in the Immediate window <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, you can monitor what is happening, if you uncomment the `Debug.Print` sections. Note that `Join` will fail if error values, but you can always create a loop like it is done for `mData` which possibly (probably) contains error values.
- It will allow different worksheets for source and destination data.
- If will allow source and destination data starting in different rows.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub checkFiles()
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\Anyone\DXF"
    Const FileExt As String = "DXF" ' Not case-sensitive i.e. 'DXF = dxf'
    Const fFound As String = "Yes"
    Const fNotFound As String = "No"
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirst As String = "B2"
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirst As String = "F2"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim rng As Range      ' (Source and Destination) Data Range
    Dim Data As Variant   ' (Source and Destination) Data Array
    Dim fData() As String ' File Data Array
    Dim mData As Variant  ' Match Data Array
    Dim n As Long         ' File Data and (Match) Data Array Elements Counter
    
    ' Write values from Source Range to Data Array.
    Set rng = defineColumnRange(defineRange(wb.Worksheets(srcName), srcFirst))
    Data = getColumn(rng)
    'Debug.Print "Source Data:" & vbLf & Join(Application.Transpose(Data), vbLf)
    
    ' Write file paths to File Data Array.
    fData = getFilePaths(FolderPath, "*." & FileExt)
    'Debug.Print "File Data - File Paths:" & vbLf & Join(fData, vbLf)
    
    ' Replace file paths with file names without file extension.
    For n = LBound(fData) To UBound(fData)
        fData(n) = FileFromPath(fData(n), True) ' 'True' means no extension.
    Next n
    'Debug.Print "File Data - File Names:" & vbLf & Join(fData, vbLf)
    
    ' Write 'matches' to Match Data Array.
    mData = Application.Match(Data, fData, 0)
    'Debug.Print "Match Data:"
    'For n = 1 To UBound(mData)
    '    Debug.Print mData(n, 1)
    'Next
    
    ' Overwrite values in Data Array with 'matching results'.
    For n = 1 To UBound(Data) ' or 'UBound(mData)'
        If IsNumeric(mData(n, 1)) Then
            Data(n, 1) = fFound
        Else
            Data(n, 1) = fNotFound
        End If
    Next n
    'Debug.Print "Destination Data:" & vbLf _
        & Join(Application.Transpose(Data), vbLf)
    
    ' Write values from Data Array to Destination Range.
    With defineRange(wb.Worksheets(dstName), dstFirst)
        Dim RowOffset As Long: RowOffset = .Row - rng.Row
        Dim ColumnOffset As Long: ColumnOffset = .Column - rng.Column
        Set rng = .Worksheet.Range(rng.Offset(RowOffset, ColumnOffset).Address)
    End With
    rng.Value = Data
    
End Sub

Function defineRange( _
    ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal RangeAddress As String) _
As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set defineRange = ws.Range(RangeAddress)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function defineColumnRange( _
    FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If Not FirstCell Is Nothing Then
        With FirstCell
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
            Set rng = rng.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                Set defineColumnRange = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Function

Function getColumn( _
    rng As Range) _
As Variant
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If InStr(rng.Address, ":") > 0 Then
            getColumn = rng.Value
        Else
            Dim Data As Variant
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            Data(1, 1) = rng.Value
            getColumn = Data
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function getFilePaths( _
    ByVal FolderPath As String, _
    Optional ByVal FilePattern As String = "") _
As Variant
    Dim ExecString As String
    ExecString = "cmd /c Dir """ & FolderPath & Application.PathSeparator _
        & FilePattern & """ /b/s"
    getFilePaths = Filter(Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell") _
        .Exec(ExecString).StdOut.ReadAll, vbCrLf), ".") ' 'vbCrLf' is a must.
End Function

Function FileFromPath( _
    ByVal FilePath As String, _
    Optional ByVal NoExtension As Boolean = False) _
As String
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = Right(FilePath, _
        Len(FilePath) - InStrRev(FilePath, "\"))
    If NoExtension Then
        FileName = Left(FileName, InStrRev(FileName, ".") - 1)
    End If
    FileFromPath = FileName
End Function
```